# Choosing informative class names

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions, computer-science, classname

I'm having a hard time coming up with informative and useful class names. One class I am have this problem with makes requests to websites/servers. I thought it would only be fitting to name this class `ServerRequest` which is within the package of `ServerServices`. This package also contains the classes `ServerData` and `ServerImage`. `ServerData` parses the response from `ServerRequest` and creates objects. `ServerImage` will copy remote images to local machine using `ServerRequest`.

I don't feel like it's good practice to prefix every class name. At the same time I don't want to simply name the classes `Request`, `Data`, and `Image`. Without the prefix the names lose their meaning, not to mention how common they become.

What are good conventions to use, beyond CamelCase and using nouns?

What are some examples of class names to use for the three classes above?

Comment: Use anonymous inner classes instead ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you're going to have `ServerData`, `MailData`, `UserData` then the prefix is certainly a good idea to know which `Data` we're talking about. But if class-name confusion isn't a problem (also depends on the scale of the project...) you could regroup all your classes under the `something.here.server` package and keep simple class names like `Request`, `Data` and `Image`.

It's all about aiming for maximum readability and code clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a `ServerClient` that returns a `ServerResponse`, which is in turn parsed by a `ServerResponseParser` into a `ServerData`. I'm not quite clear on the "image" part. Would it be an `ImageRequester` which uses `ServerClient` to get `ServerImage`s?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the Classname needs to express what Data is saved/parsed/requested, the Packagename groups a subset of functionality of your application.

So we have a UserImage in package user.data.roster for example, so everything that has todo with showing a roster of the users goes there.